# Entity Framework Extensions: BulkMerge with update statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

Is there any way to run an update statement when using the BulkMerge of Entity Framework Extensions?
For instance, if the record exists, sum the current value in the database plus the value in the parameter list. If the record doest exists then just insert the value of the parameter list in the database.

I'm looking for something to include like (x => new Animal {Age = x.Age + parameters.Age});

In terms of SQL it would be something like this merge:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET      
        TARGET.ColumNumber = TARGET.ColumNumber + SOURCE.ColumNumber
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT...
```

Comment: you could try this https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to add an hardcoded formula.

Here is an example by using PostConfiguration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/s8QF4t

```
context.BulkMerge(list, options => {
    options.PostConfiguration = bulk => {
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Single(x => x.SourceName == "Description").FormulaUpdate = "DestinationTable.Name + ';' + StagingTable.Description";
    };
});
```

Here is an example by mapping all your columns: https://dotnetfiddle.net/enOEQF

```
context.BulkMerge(list, options => {
    options.ColumnMappings.Add(new Z.BulkOperations.ColumnMapping<Customer>(x => x.CustomerID, true));
    options.ColumnMappings.Add(new Z.BulkOperations.ColumnMapping<Customer>(x => x.Name));

    var columnMapping = new Z.BulkOperations.ColumnMapping<Customer>(x => x.Description);
    columnMapping.FormulaUpdate = "DestinationTable.Name + ';' + StagingTable.Description";
    options.ColumnMappings.Add(columnMapping);
});
```

Both examples concatenate 2 fields but as you see, you can use any kind of Formula. It's important to use the `DestinationTable` and `StagingTable` alias

#### DestinationTable

The DestinationTable is the table on which the data will be updated. So the `TARGET` table in your example.

#### StagingTable

The StagingTable is the table on which data is taken from for the update. So the `SOURCE` table in your example.

Comment: are you aware that the merge doesn't work with Oracle? It woks great with SQL Server but with oracle it just does the inserts but the UPDATEs are dont. I will rise the proper ticket in github.

Comment: Thank you @menta, no we were not aware. You are the first to report it, we will look at it with the issue you opened.